# Switching between Reserved instance and convertible instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, reserved-instances

I have a Standard reserved instance for almost 7 months now and planning to switch the Standard reserved to convertible RI,
In the beginning i have signed up for 3 years contract, if i convert the standard RI to Convertible now (after 7 months)  will my term will start over again from month 1 or will it continue from month 7.

Comment: Are you sure you can change from standard to convertible RIs? Alternately you could sell your existing RI and moving to a savings plan.

Comment: i think i saw it somewhere, can we not convert the existing RI :/

Comment: Go into the console and try it, just don't hit the "submit" button. RIs used to be quite inflexible, they've gotten more flexible over time but I'm not sure they're quite that flexible yet. I don't use them often so I may not be up to date

Comment: i did check and there is no way we can convert the existing Standard RI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to sell the reserved instances and then buy new convertible ones. You can modify some aspects of a reserved instance, but you can't go from a reserved instance to a convertible type without selling/rebuying.

See here [for](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/reserved-instances-types.html) more info.